# A subgroup $H$ is normal in $G$ iff $H$ is the union of some conjugacy classes of $G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

How to show that:

> A subgroup $H$ is normal in $G$ iff $H$ is the union of some conjugacy classes of $G$.

Comment: What is your definition for a *normal subgroup*? Because *union of some conjugacy classes* seems a perfect legitimate definition for normal subgroups.

Answer (score 14):

Consider the  relation on $G$ given by
$$
a \sim b \qquad\text{if and only if}\qquad \text{there exists $g \in G$ such that $b = g^{-1} a g$},
$$
so this is the conjugacy relation. It is clearly an equivalence relation, so one may consider the conjugacy classes $[a] = \{ g^{-1} a g : g \in G \}$, which then form a partition of $G$.

Now by definition a subgroup $H$ is normal in $G$ if and only if

> if $a \in H$ and $b \sim a$, then $b \in H$,

or in other words,

> if $a \in H$, then $[a] \subseteq H$.

If $a \in H$, we have then $a \in \{ a \} \subseteq [a] \subseteq H$. It follows that
$$
H = \bigcup_{a \in H} \{ a \} = \bigcup_{a \in H} [a].
$$

Answer (score 3):

Hints:

Suppose

$$H\lhd G\implies \forall\,h\in H\;\wedge\;\forall\,g\in G\,,\;\;h^g:=g^{-1}hg\in H$$

The other direction is almost trivial: denote by $\,[g]\;$ the conjugation class of an element $\,g\in G\,$ , then

$$\forall\,h\in H\;,\;g\in G\;,\;\;h^g\in[h]\subset H\;\ldots\ldots$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Look at the group action of G on itself by conjugation.

Comment: please avoid group action

Comment: $G$ doesn't act on $H$ by conjugation unless $H$ is normal, which makes this hint fairly unhelpful.

Comment: That's true, thank you. I changed it to the action of $G$ on itself.